# Speeding yfinance functions in Excel

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, xlwings, yfinance

I am trying to speed up the results from a UDF called in Excel. The formula simply reads the current stock price. The formula below works fin, but when you copy it to over 100 stock symbols, it takes around 1 minute to refresh:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import requests
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

@xw.func
def current_price(name):
name = yf.Ticker(name)
return name.info['currentPrice']
```

Let s say stock symbols are in column A. In B1, you can enter the formula: = current_price(A1)

This works fine, but inefficient when you work with a very long list in Column A.

I was trying to work with on e big array as below, but it s not working:

```
@xw.func
def current_price_v2(name):
name = yf.Ticker(name)
return [[cell.info['currentPrice'] for cell in row] for row in name]
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.